# how to make payment amount editable?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm building an app using an external payment proc. library.

Im trying it out and and for now I can only make payments for a fixed amount:

```
public static final BigDecimal DUMMY_ITEM_UNIT_PRICE = new BigDecimal("100");
```

Could someone help me out, I want the amount to be editable (whatever amount is entered in a particular `EditText`.

Looking forward to any help you guys can give me!!
Thanks!!!

Comment: How can you edit something if the variable is final ? Can't you create a new instance ?

Comment: Hi Shree! It´s my first time working on an app, how would I go about creating a new instance? Thanks!

Comment: I've added it as an answer, Ask if any confusion is left.

Answer (score 0):

Do like,

```
BigDecimal DUMMY_ITEM_UNIT_PRICE_Editable = new BigDecimal("200");
```